# Isn't SecurityContextHolder a Bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

Trying to Autowire SecurityContextHolder
I get error

```
required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder' that could not be found.
```

Turns out that it is available from any part of the code like

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

How come it isn't a bean and how does it get initialized under the hood?
Are there other static utility classes like that available to be consumed from anywhere and how do I find them?

Comment: It isn't a bean, it internally uses a `ThreadLocal` to hold the current user. This is set by the spring security filter chain. There are several of such like the `RequestContextHolder`, `LocaleContextHolder` to name a few.

Comment: This method exists to allow you to get access to the `Authentication` in places where you _can't_ inject it. If you try to autowire the `SecurityContextHolder` just to get the `Authentication`, autowire the latter instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`SecurityContextHolder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html) is a utility class which declares a bunch of `static` methods, which can be accessed using class name.

It doesn't make much sense to instantiate utility classes (their constructors are usually private to emphasize that), and for that reason `SecurityContextHolder` is not a Bean in the Context, hence there's no way (*and no need*) to inject it.

The purpose `SecurityContextHolder` to facilitate access to the [`SecurityContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContext.html), which contains information specific to the currently authenticated user. Also, `SecurityContextHolder` offers various strategies for managing `SecurityContext`:

- `MODE_THREADLOCAL` is the default one, that is suitable for so-called servlet-based Web Application, which are using thread-per-request model. In this case, each thread would have its own context and Spring uses [`TreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) to manage the context.
- `MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL` is similar to the previous one with one difference - it allows to use multiple threads per request, and if we spawn a new thread it inherits the context of the parent thread.
- `MODE_GLOBAL` - is not appropriate for server use. This strategy is not based on `TreadLocal`, every thread is expected to see the same context. And can be used in a standalone application (for instance in a Swing client).

Here's a short quote from the [Spring Security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.9.RELEASE/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-securitycontextholder) (*have a closer at this link if you want to learn more*):

> **10.1. SecurityContextHolder**
>
> At the heart of Spring Security’s authentication model is the
> `SecurityContextHolder`. It contains the `SecurityContext`.
> securitycontextholder
>
> [image]
>
> The `SecurityContextHolder` is where Spring Security stores the
> details of who is authenticated. Spring Security does not care how the
> `SecurityContextHolder` is populated. If it contains a value, then it
> is used as the currently authenticated user.
>
> ...

So, as a recap, the main purpose of `SecurityContextHolder` is to manage `SecurityContext`. And security context is meant to provide access to the user's [`Authentication`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html).

`Authentication` represents the currently authenticated user. And since `Authentication` a Bean, it can be provided through dependency injection in another Bean, for instance as a method parameter.

Let's have a look at an example. Assume we have a controller which has an endpoint returning an instance of `Foo` which requires some user's information from the `Authentication`:

```
@RestController
public class FooController {
    
    @GetMapping("/foo")
    Foo getFoo(Authentication a) {
        
        return FooUtils.generateFoo(a);
    }
}
```

It makes use of the `generateFoo()` method by passing `Authentication` injected a parameter. Method `generateFoo()` located in the `FooUtils` which is a utility class.

```
public class FooUtils {
    public static Foo generateFoo(Authentication a) {
        
        return new Foo(a.getPrincipal());
    }
}
```

`Authentication` can't be injected in the methods of `FooUtils`, since it's a not a Bean, therefore it's being handed out by the caller. If we imagine that chain of calls would be longer, i.e. there would be more actions in between the calling endpoint method and `FooUtils.generateFoo()` it would not be very convenient to pass around `Authentication` through several methods where it's not going to be used.

Instead, can make use of the `SecurityContextHolder` and obtain `Authentication` right on the spot inside the `FooUtils`:

```
public class FooUtils {
    public static Foo generateFoo() {
        Authentication a = SecurityContextHolder
            .getContext()
            .getAuthentication();
        
        return new Foo(a.getPrincipal());
    }
}
```